# How to select exact match in database using Vue?

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js

Im trying to make simple site using Vue.js and MySQL database.

I've got database with 3 columns:

1) id (simple numbers from 1 to 600)

2) username (random 7-8 numbers and letters)

3) path (path to file)

Firstly it was working that way that I choose ID and then when I made:

```
 if(this.userid > 0 )
```

Everything is working. I change ID to username and if username was a number everything was working. How can I make condition that if username is EXACT MATCH from username column then show results? I was trying to add "===" but its not working.

This is my ajaxfile.php

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$condition  = "1";
if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
    $condition  = " username=".$_GET['userid'];
}
$userData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users WHERE ".$condition );

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userData)){

    $response[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

This is my Vue script in index.html

```
<script>
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#myapp',
                data: {
                    users: "",
                    userid: 0,
                    isHidden: false,
                    errors: [],
                    userid: null
                },
                methods: {
                    recordByID: function(){
                        if(this.userid === this.userid) {

                            axios.get('ajaxfile.php', {
                                params: {
                                    userid: this.userid
                                }

                            })
                            .then(function (response) {
                                app.users = response.data;
                            })

                            .catch(function (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                        }
                        if (!this.userid) {
        this.errors.push('Error here');
      }
            }
                }

            })

        </script>
```

Probably it's simple to fix but for now I only crush my site.

Comment: `if(this.userid === this.userid)` does not make sense, you are comparing  same value with itself.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but how can I compare is value typed by user is exact match to value in username column?

Comment: First you should not compare username on client side, you should send it to the server and then form server you should return an error or success report, in that report there should be a status which represents weather the user exists and is valid,  and then you can show the relevant information to the user.

Comment: So this is wrong?
https://makitweb.com/fetch-records-from-mysql-database-with-vue-js-and-php/

Comment: In his case the userid is integer so he is just checking if the ID is greater than 0. But that's not the right way to do it, his code is not secure. You should use some security best practices or you may use some framework like laravel for php.